# how to set datepicker dialog in android to yesterday date

Tags: android, date, datepicker

I have a datepicker code which sets current date to datepicker dialog

how can i set this date to yesterdays date, specially during ,month end will it keep  yesterdays date and previous month, for example if on 1st feb we check it should display 31st jan and from on 2nd feb should show 1st feb and so on.

```
 final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        maxyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        maxmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        maxday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // set date picker as current date
            DatePickerDialog _date =   new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, maxyear,maxmonth,
                    maxday){
                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                {   
                    if (year < 2014)
                        view.updateDate(2014, mmonth, mday);

                    if (monthOfYear < 12 && year == 2014)
                        view.updateDate(2014, 12, mday);

                    if (dayOfMonth < 31 && year == 2014 && monthOfYear == 12)
                        view.updateDate(2014, 12, 31);

                    if (year > maxyear)
                        view.updateDate(maxyear, maxmonth, maxday);

                    if (monthOfYear > maxmonth && year == maxyear)
                        view.updateDate(maxyear, maxmonth, maxday);

                    if (dayOfMonth > maxday && year == maxyear && monthOfYear == maxmonth)
                        view.updateDate(maxyear, maxmonth, maxday);

                }
            };
            return _date;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to set it to the day before `today`or the day before the date selected in the datepicker?

Comment: the datepicker should set max date to be selected to yesterday i.e user cannot select todays date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();   

now.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); 

int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH); // it's zero based
int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

DatePicker datePicker.updateDate(year, month, day);
```

Comment: would that also solve the month end issue as i have described earlier

Comment: Pretty sure yes. Calendar does the heavy lifting for you when adding/subtracting dates. Give it a try and tell me what happened

Comment: will know about it tomorrow it would be 1st feb

Comment: I believe you can change your phone's date in config for that hahah

Answer (score 1):

**Update Date using update**

```
mDatePicker.setTitle("Please select date");
mDatePicker.updateDate(1994, 6, 12);

// TODO Hide Future Date Here
                 mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```